# Will a door edge guard cause rust or other issues?

Tags: rust, door, rubber

I would like to place a u-shaped rubber door guard provided with double sided tape along the edges of my car doors to avoid damage against other cars or against walls.

I wonder whether this protection will cause water to be trapped and on the long term additional rust.

Answer (score 0):

Less likely from the rubber than from a chipped edge when there is no guard.

Any damaged coating will give the metal chance to return to its natural state which is what it wants to do chemically...

Comment: I have a spot where the colour and top coat are chipped but the bottom (rust protection?) pinkish paint is still intact. I guess I should retouch it first.